# The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Object?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic, VxStatus?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, velocity

```
[Issue 1 :)'. ][1]
```

The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Object?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic, VxStatus?

Trying to update the cart total using Vxbuilder or Vxconsumer but this errors pops in

```
class _CartTotal extends StatelessWidget {
  final CartModel _cart = (VxState.store as MyStore).cart;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          VxBuilder(
            mutations: {RemoveMutation},
            //notifications: {},
            builder: (context, _ ){
            return "\$${_cart.totalPrice}"
              .text
              .xl5
              .color(context.theme.accentColor)
              .make();
          }, 
          );
          30.widthBox,
          TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: "Buying not supported yet".text.center.make(),
                    ));
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all(context.theme.buttonColor)),
                  child: "Buy".text.xl3.color(Colors.black).make())
              .w32(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
'''
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
 builder: (context, _ ){
```

You are declaring a function, this function takes 3 arguments, but you are only passing 2, add a third argument:

```
 builder: (context, _, __) {
```

Comment: It's other way around. I just remove the second argument and it worked.